# Retrofit, Android Can I observe how much data I send to server, when json is big (7 mb)

Tags: android, rest, retrofit, retrofit2

Can I observe data status, or amount of data which server already received from a device, when json file I send is big. For example 6-15 mb.

Answer (score 0):

Well If you are sending Json which is a string. I thing you can just calculate the bytes :-

```
 byte[] utf8Bytes = json.toString.getBytes("UTF-8");
 byte[] utf32Bytes = json.toString.getBytes("UTF-32");
```

> The default encoding of JSON is UTF-8

Comment: Okey, I got it, but this is just amount of data i ll send. Can I track data already transfered to server. I thing it has someting to do with transfort layer in OSI model https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model